# Docker: Set MSSQL password from a secret

Tags: sql-server, docker, docker-swarm, docker-secrets

I'm trying to set my MSSQL password's from a secret, but I don't know why it seems I'm not properly setting my secret as a password.

This is my YAML file:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  notguiridb:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
    environment:
      ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
      MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD_FILE: /run/secrets/mysecret4
    secrets:
      - source: mysecret4
        target: mysecret4

secrets:
  mysecret4:
    external: true
```

Then I checked that the secret was the one I expected, but even doing that it says the login failed, so I suspect the environment variable `MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD_FILE` does not really work.

```
$ docker exec -it 5fd bash
$ mssql@5fd8471a22c4:/$ cat /run/secrets/mysecret4
"Pa55W0rd!1234*"

$ docker exec -it 5fd /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -U sa -P Pa55w0rd!1234*
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Login failed for user 'sa'..
$ docker exec -it 5fd /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -U sa -P "Pa55w0rd!1234*"
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Login failed for user 'sa'..
```

Comment: Try without the quotes in the file.  They may be stripped when you present a double-quoted string in the command.

Comment: It's worth noting that when you run SQL Server in a container, when container starts the SA password is read and stored in `master`. This means that if you change the environment variable and restart the container, if you've got the same volume attached as the initial run, the password **will not change**. You have to change it through SQL Server or create a new volume.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$ mssql@5fd8471a22c4:/$ cat /run/secrets/mysecret4
"Pa55W0rd!1234*"
```

Remove the surrounding quotes in the file. They will be stripped when you present a double-quoted string in the command.